# Generar matriz de datos con LEFT JOINS en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buena tarde ... tengo esta tabla temporal con la siguiente estructura :

```
create table ##PAC_ID_TEMP ( Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),NHC varchar(30), Id_Ficha_IOS int) CREATE NONCLUSTERED  INDEX Idx1 ON ##PAC_ID_TEMP(NHC);
```

La cual utilizo para filtrar la información que deseo mostrar, esta tabla la utilizo en el siguiente script.

```html
 
 
 




select  f.Id_Ficha_IOS,
 e1.Id_Enfermedad, e1.Id_FichaIOS, e1.Id_Medicamento, e1.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e1.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e2.Id_Enfermedad, e2.Id_FichaIOS, e2.Id_Medicamento, e2.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e2.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e3.Id_Enfermedad, e3.Id_FichaIOS, e3.Id_Medicamento, e3.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e3.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e4.Id_Enfermedad, e4.Id_FichaIOS, e4.Id_Medicamento, e4.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e4.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e5.Id_Enfermedad, e5.Id_FichaIOS, e5.Id_Medicamento, e5.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e5.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e6.Id_Enfermedad, e6.Id_FichaIOS, e6.Id_Medicamento, e6.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e6.Id_TipoMedicamento
 from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f
 left join (
  select e.Id_FichaIOS ,  Id_Enfermedad , Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  , Id_TipoMedicamento , Id_Medicamento    
  from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f 
  left join Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS e
  on f.Id_Ficha_IOS =  e.Id_FichaIOS
  left join Medicamento_Administrado m
  on e.Id_FichaIOS = m.Id_FichaIOS 
 )e1
 on f.Id_Ficha_IOS = e1.Id_FichaIOS
 left join 
 (
  select e.Id_FichaIOS ,  Id_Enfermedad , Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  , Id_TipoMedicamento , Id_Medicamento    
  from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f 
  left join Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS e
  on f.Id_Ficha_IOS =  e.Id_FichaIOS
  left join Medicamento_Administrado m
  on e.Id_FichaIOS = m.Id_FichaIOS
 )e2
 on f.Id_Ficha_IOS = e2.Id_FichaIOS
 left join (
  select e.Id_FichaIOS ,  Id_Enfermedad , Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  , Id_TipoMedicamento , Id_Medicamento    
  from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f 
  left join Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS e
  on f.Id_Ficha_IOS =  e.Id_FichaIOS
  left join Medicamento_Administrado m
  on e.Id_FichaIOS = m.Id_FichaIOS
 )e3
 on f.Id_Ficha_IOS = e3.Id_FichaIOS
 left join (
  select e.Id_FichaIOS ,  Id_Enfermedad , Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  , Id_TipoMedicamento , Id_Medicamento    
  from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f 
  left join Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS e
  on f.Id_Ficha_IOS =  e.Id_FichaIOS
  left join Medicamento_Administrado m
  on e.Id_FichaIOS = m.Id_FichaIOS
 )e4
 on f.Id_Ficha_IOS = e4.Id_FichaIOS
 left join (
  select e.Id_FichaIOS ,  Id_Enfermedad , Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  , Id_TipoMedicamento , Id_Medicamento    
  from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f 
  left join Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS e
  on f.Id_Ficha_IOS =  e.Id_FichaIOS
  left join Medicamento_Administrado m
  on e.Id_FichaIOS = m.Id_FichaIOS
 )e5
 on f.Id_Ficha_IOS = e5.Id_FichaIOS
  left join (
  select e.Id_FichaIOS ,  Id_Enfermedad , Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  , Id_TipoMedicamento , Id_Medicamento    
  from ##PAC_ID_TEMP f 
  left join Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS e
  on f.Id_Ficha_IOS =  e.Id_FichaIOS
  left join Medicamento_Administrado m
  on e.Id_FichaIOS = m.Id_FichaIOS
 )e6
 on f.Id_Ficha_IOS = e6.Id_FichaIOS
 group by f.Id_Ficha_IOS,
 e1.Id_Enfermedad, e1.Id_FichaIOS, e1.Id_Medicamento, e1.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e1.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e2.Id_Enfermedad, e2.Id_FichaIOS, e2.Id_Medicamento, e2.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e2.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e3.Id_Enfermedad, e3.Id_FichaIOS, e3.Id_Medicamento, e3.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e3.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e4.Id_Enfermedad, e4.Id_FichaIOS, e4.Id_Medicamento, e4.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e4.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e5.Id_Enfermedad, e5.Id_FichaIOS, e5.Id_Medicamento, e5.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e5.Id_TipoMedicamento,
 e6.Id_Enfermedad, e6.Id_FichaIOS, e6.Id_Medicamento, e6.Id_Tipo_Enfermedad, e6.Id_TipoMedicamento
```

Lo que espero obtener con este script es una matriz como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este resultado se espera considerando que la data que tengo registrada es la siguiente:

```html
Id_FichaIOS Id_Paciente Fecha                   Fecha_Enfermedad        Id_Tipo_Enfermedad Id_Enfermedad
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------------ -------------
213         9607        2017-06-27 12:02:36.030 2017-05-24 00:00:00.000 3                  13521        
213         9607        2017-06-27 12:03:48.540 2017-05-24 00:00:00.000 3                  68           
213         9607        2017-06-27 12:04:52.200 2017-05-24 00:00:00.000 1                  26           
213         9607        2017-06-27 12:07:13.380 2017-05-24 00:00:00.000 2                  2            
213         9607        2017-06-27 12:09:24.630 2017-06-07 00:00:00.000 1                  22           
199         9560        2017-06-26 14:21:54.743 2017-05-11 00:00:00.000 2                  6            
199         9560        2017-06-26 14:24:43.243 2017-05-15 00:00:00.000 1                  20           
199         9560        2017-06-26 14:25:47.050 2017-05-31 00:00:00.000 2                  2
```

Sin embargo tengo dos problemas, la estructura de joins se tarda demasiado y no obtengo el resultado esperado, obtengo algo como esto...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pueden orientarme un poco por favor.

Gracias.

-------------------editado en este punto ------------------------------------

El script que aportaste cambio a esto :

```html
select 'max (case when  enf.Nro ='+ cast ( Conteo as varchar (5)) + ' ' +'then '+ ' ' + x.Campo+ ' ' +'else null end)' +x.Campo+ cast (Nro as varchar(2)) 
from
(
 select Conteo, #row, Campo, Nro,Id_FichaIOS, Id_Enfermedad, Fecha_Enfermedad
 from
 (
  select #vt.Conteo Conteo,   tt.Campo Campo,#row
  from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
  cross apply
  (
   select Campo , 
   ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) #row
   from TablaCampoInformes
   where Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
  )tt

  where #vt.Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS'
  --order by Conteo, #row
 )n
 left join 
 (
  SELECT  Id_FichaIOS,
  Id_Enfermedad, Fecha_Enfermedad,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_FichaIOS ORDER BY Id_Enfermedad) AS Nro
  FROM Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS --where Id_FichaIOS in (199,213)

 )enf
 on n.Conteo = enf.Nro
 --
)x
order by Id_FichaIOS, Nro, #row
```

Esta sección del script, me dice cuantas columnas debo generar :

```
select #vt.Conteo Conteo,   tt.Campo Campo,#row
    from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
    cross apply
    (
        select Campo , 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) #row
        from TablaCampoInformes
        where Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
    )tt
```

Mi problema, es que no logro generar la cantidad de case, indicada por esta tabla

------------------------------ESCRIPT PARA RESOLVER DINAMICAMENTE LA CANTIDAD DE CASE A GENERAR -------------------------------

```html
select 'max (case when enf.Nro = ' + cast(Conteo as varchar(4) )+ ' ' +'then enf.' + Campo + ' ' +'else null end) as ' +Campo+cast (Conteo as varchar(4))
from
(
 select #vt.Conteo Conteo,   tt.Campo Campo,#row
 from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
 cross apply
 (
  select Campo , 
  ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) #row
  from TablaCampoInformes
  where Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
 )tt

 where #vt.Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS'
 --order by Conteo, #row
)x 
order by Conteo, #row
```

Comment: Hola Emerson, ¿qué sistema de base de datos utilizas? Y¿cómo no obtienes el resultado esperado? ¿Te da error o cómo difiere de lo esperado?

Comment: Gracias .. utilizo SQL Server v17.1... el resultado obtenido .... que no es el esperado lo actualice en la pregunta ...Efectivamente ... el resultado difiere del esperado.

Comment: Me permití editar, para colocar la etiqueta [tag:sql-server] y quitar el texto totalmente en mayúsculas.

Comment: Entiendo... Gracias ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema más importante no es el filtro de los datos mediante `##PAC_ID_TEMP` sino la "transpocisión" de filas a columnas. Hacer esto siempre trae aparejado alguno que otro dolor de cabeza, uno es armar la propia consulta que si bien no es algo complejo, no suele ser algo habitual de hacer. Pero el problema más complicado, es que debemos establecer un "límite" a la cantidad de columnas, en tu caso lo has establecido en 5, pero si tuvieras que ampliarlo deberías reescribir la consulta cada vez, a menos claro, que transformes todo en una sentencia dinámica, que también tiene otros problemas, pero esto último lo voy a descartar por ahora.

Nos vamos a enfocar a la salida que has solicitado, para lo cual voy a plantearte una solución bastante básica pero cumple con lo que pides. En primer lugar creamos y llenamos una tabla de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS(
    Id_FichaIOS         INT,
    Id_Paciente         INT,
    Fecha               DATETIME,
    Fecha_Enfermedad    DATETIME,
    Id_Tipo_Enfermedad  INT,
    Id_Enfermedad       INT
)

INSERT INTO #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS (Id_FichaIOS,Id_Paciente,Fecha,Fecha_Enfermedad,Id_Tipo_Enfermedad,Id_Enfermedad)
VALUES  (213,        9607,        '2017-06-27 12:02:36.030', '2017-05-24 00:00:00.000', 3,          13521),
        (213,        9607,        '2017-06-27 12:03:48.540', '2017-05-24 00:00:00.000', 3,                  68),           
        (213,        9607,        '2017-06-27 12:04:52.200', '2017-05-24 00:00:00.000', 1,                  26),           
        (213,        9607,        '2017-06-27 12:07:13.380', '2017-05-24 00:00:00.000', 2,                  2),            
        (213,        9607,        '2017-06-27 12:09:24.630', '2017-06-07 00:00:00.000', 1,                  22),           
        (199,        9560,        '2017-06-26 14:21:54.743', '2017-05-11 00:00:00.000', 2,                  6),            
        (199,        9560,        '2017-06-26 14:24:43.243', '2017-05-15 00:00:00.000', 1,                  20),           
        (199,        9560,        '2017-06-26 14:25:47.050', '2017-05-31 00:00:00.000', 2,                  2)
```

Esto simplemente aprovechando los datos que has indicado. Ahora veamos la consulta:

```
SELECT  ENF.Id_FichaIOS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = 1 THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'Enfermedad1',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = 2 THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'Enfermedad2',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = 3 THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'Enfermedad3',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = 4 THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'Enfermedad4',
    MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = 5 THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'Enfermedad5'
    FROM (  SELECT  Id_FichaIOS,
            Id_Enfermedad,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_FichaIOS ORDER BY Id_Enfermedad) AS Nro
            FROM #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS
        ) ENF
    GROUP BY ENF.Id_FichaIOS
```

La salida:

```
Id_FichaIOS Enfermedad1 Enfermedad2 Enfermedad3 Enfermedad4 Enfermedad5
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
199,00      2,00        6,00        20,00        NULL       NULL
213,00      2,00        22,00       26,00        68,00      13.521,00
```

Lo que hacemos en primer lugar con esto:

```
SELECT  Id_FichaIOS,
            Id_Enfermedad,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_FichaIOS ORDER BY Id_Enfermedad) AS Nro
            FROM #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS
```

Es numerar cada enfermedad por `Id_FichaIOS`, luego en el `SELECT` final agrupado por el mismo campo y hacemos:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = 1 THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'Enfermedad1'
```

Que simplemente nos recupera la enfermedad que ya hemos numerado como la 1, la función agregada nos permite lograr la agrupación final.

#### Configuración de cantidad de columnas de forma dinámica

Agrego esto para complementar un poco la respuesta. La idea es como definir la cantidad de columnas que queremos de forma dinámica. No hay muchas opciones, es más calculo que esta es la única forma. Veamos

En primer lugar, tenemos una tabla que establece la cantidad de columnas en función a la cantidad de registros, algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE #ValoresPorTabla(
    Conteo  INT
)   

INSERT INTO #ValoresPorTabla (Conteo)
VALUES  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)
```

Con esta tabla, se debe crear una sentencia dinámica, y luego ejecutarla con `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT   ENF.Id_FichaIOS,' 
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(10) + '        MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,T.Conteo) + ' THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS ''Enfermedad' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,T.Conteo) + ''','
        FROM #ValoresPorTabla T

SELECT @SQL = LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL) - 1)

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(10) + '
    FROM (  SELECT  Id_FichaIOS,
            Id_Enfermedad,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id_FichaIOS ORDER BY Id_Enfermedad) AS Nro
            FROM #Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS
        ) ENF
    GROUP BY ENF.Id_FichaIOS
'
PRINT @SQL

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

**NOTA**: La otra posibilidad es que `#ValoresPorTabla` tenga un único registro con la cantidad de columnas, en ese caso lo que varía es que deberemos usar un ciclo `WHILE` que vaya de 1 a `Conteo` con el que completamos cada una de las columnas de la consulta, pero la idea es la misma.

Comment: Gracias... tal como lo mencionaste  **"a menos claro, que transformes todo en una sentencia dinámica, que también tiene otros problemas"** ... Y en efecto , todo lo estoy construyendo con sentencias dinámicas, pero conceptual y funcionalmente tu respuesta es una solución a mi problema

Comment: Y por si esto fuera poco... justo como también lo mencionaste **"Pero el problema más complicado, es que debemos establecer un "límite" a la cantidad de columnas"** , el numero de columnas se define por una tabla que genera un conteo de la cantidad de columnas que debo generar. Sin embargo tu aporte me es de gran utilidad. Gracias

Comment: @EmersonRios: En ese caso, lo que haría es construir un variable `@SQL` con una sentencia como la que te pasé pero deberías incorporar tantos `MAX(CASE WHEN ENF.Nro = N THEN ENF.Id_Enfermedad ELSE NULL END) AS 'EnfermedadN'` como columnas quieras, por ultimo la ejecutas con un `exec sp_executesql @SQL`, el problema lo vas a tener por el limite de tamaño de la variable, y también por que hay un limite de cantidad de columnas en un select, que si no me equivoco es de 4096. Saludos.

Comment: Entonces ... añado ... añadiré información editando la pregunta original...

Comment: En efecto... nunca llegare al limite de columnas, quizás solo sean  15, sin embargo deben ser 15 columnas con _n_ registros .... Este es mi problema ..

Comment: Veras  **##ValoresTabla** indica que para la tabla **Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS**  debo generar 5 columnas, pero con _n_ registros , eso es lo que intento en la versión de tu script que coloque en la edición de la pregunta

Comment: Listo  !!!!  Ya lo resolví ... Edito la respuesta al final para mostrar la solución.

Comment: De nuevo gracias ...