# Generar matriz de datos SQL PostgreSql

Tags: sql, matriz, subconsultas, datos, google-chart-api

Buenas tengo que realizar unas graficas y quier reutilizar las consultas para buscar usuario y fecha tambien, lo que sucede es que tengo la siguiente tabla de respuestas.

[image: Tabla de respuestas]

La tabla se hara mas grande, busco graficar, hasta el momento he logrado hacer la consulta.

```
(select fecha, cast(avg(promedio) as decimal(10,1)) as n1, 0 as n2, 0 as n3, 0 as n4 from (select cast(avg(nota) as decimal(10,1)) as promedio, 
fecha from respuesta group by fecha) as c1 where promedio = 5 group by fecha) union all
(select fecha, 0 as n1, cast(avg(promedio) as decimal(10,1)) as n2, 0 as n3, 0 as n4 from (select cast(avg(nota) as decimal(10,1)) as promedio, 
 fecha from respuesta group by fecha) as c1 where promedio < 5 and promedio >= 4 group by fecha) union all 
(select fecha, 0 as n1, 0 as n2, cast(avg(promedio) as decimal(10,1)) as n3, 0 as n4 from (select cast(avg(nota) as decimal(10,1)) as promedio, 
fecha from respuesta group by fecha) as c1 where promedio < 4 and promedio >= 3 group by fecha) union all 
(select fecha, 0 as n1, 0 as n2, 0 as n3, cast(avg(promedio) as decimal(10,1)) as n4 from (select cast(avg(nota) as decimal(10,1)) as promedio,
 fecha from respuesta group by  fecha) as c1 where promedio < 3 group by fecha) order by fecha desc limit 7
```

El resultado de la consulta me da la suigiente tabla.

[image: Consulta para promedio por rangos de notas y agrupados por fechas no repetidas]

Pero si quisiera el promedio de las notas entre 3 y 4, es decir n3 teniendo en cuenta la tabla de respuestas, n3 debo tener un dato adicional con el promedio que seria 3.3 = (3 +3.6 +3.3)/3 notas, tmbien trate de modificar la consulta pero la fecha llegaba individual, es decir 2 filas eran la misma fecha pero con promedio diferentes.

tambien trate de hacer una consulta como la encontre en el link [Generar matriz de datos con LEFT JOINS en SQL Server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103186/generar-matriz-de-datos-con-left-joins-en-sql-server)

aunque la consulta que hago no esta perfecta es lo mejor que he realizado, el promebla es que intento graficar esos datos en una grafica de linea y una de torta, pero al dejarlo asi la grafica de torta por ejemplo, dice que el 50% esta en el promedio (3.3) cuando seria el 50% esta entre el 3.9 y 3 de nota.

[image: Grafica de torta con promedio de la consulta sql]

[image: Grafico de linea]

Por favor, necesito ayuda, ya que como tengo la tabla o como esta el link, me serviria agregar el promedio por rango en esa misma tabla, ademas de necesita que busque por idusuario y fecha, donde idusuario trae los datos de un unico usuario y fecha de todos los usuarios pero desde la fecha seleccionada hacia atras.